# Invalid RSS Feed / <media>

Tags: rss

does somebody know what is wrong with my RSS Feed?

I see this message:
[image]

Line 69 is as follows:

```
<media:content url="http://elbmadame.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/perito_moreno_gletscher_titel-620x450.jpg" type="" medium="image" width="620" height="450"><media:description type="plain"><![CDATA[Patagonien: eine Reise zum Perito Moreno Gletscher. Oder: wenn hausgroße Eisbrocken fallen.]]></media:description><media:copyright>Jasmin</media:copyright></media:content>  </item>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `media:` namespace prefix without defining it as pointing to a namespace (with `xmlns:media="some namespace identifier"`)